# How to get convert an object to HTML markup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object which I want to convert to HTML markup. This is the object:

```js
var data = {
  "htmlcontent": {
    "div": {
      "p": "hello world",
      "div": {
        "p": "next content"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the HTML I would like to output from the object:

```html
<div>
   <p>hello world</p>
   <div>
      <p>next content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't know any approach to do this. I suppose if I convert the object to an  array there are chances to loose data.

Comment: Note that what you have there is an object, not JSON. Also note that Node.js seems irrelevant to the problem, so I've edited the question as such.

Comment: you are most welcomed @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: With regard to what you're trying to do, is it possible to change the object structure at all? Given it's current form, and aside from duplicate keys, it's impossible to tell if an element should be a child or a sibling. You also seem to have an extra `div` at the end of the object which isn't in the HTML example.

Comment: The object looks incorrect also, the second or succeeding "div" keys in the associative array/or object would just replace the first.

Comment: sorry by mistake i have placed older `object/json` noew **EDITED**

Comment: The new object is no good either. What if you have more `p`s inside a `div`? Also the order of the children may get mixed up as objects don't preseve the order of their keys

Comment: Can we suggest a new structure as part of the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you can control the input, I would create an object with 3 attributes:

Element {

- element: the name of the tag element (string).
- innerText: the text contents of the element (string).
- children: an array containing its children (Element).

}

You can add more attributes, this is just based on your input data.

With this you can create a custom parse function that creates the element modify its attributes and appends it to its parent recursively. I have created one sample below.

```js
/*
JSON DATA
[{
  "element": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "element": "p",
      "innerText": "hello world"
    },
    {
      "element": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "element": "p",
          "innerText": "another P"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];
*/
const jsonData = '[{"element": "div", "children": [{"element": "p", "innerText": "hello world"}, {"element": "div", "children": [{"element": "p", "innerText": "another P"} ] } ] }]';
const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);


/**
 * Representation of a DOM element in JSON format.
 * @type {{
 *   element: string,
 *   children: (undefined|!Array<!jsonElement>),
 *   innerText: string
 * }}
 */
let jsonElement;

/**
 * Parses an element from JSON.
 * @param {!jsonElement} element Element from JSON to parse.
 * @param {!DOMElement} parentNode Element to which append this one.
 */
const parseElement = (element, parentNode = document.body) => {
  if (!element.element) throw new Error('Must define element.');
  const domElement = document.createElement(element.element);
  if (element.innerText) domElement.innerText = element.innerText;
  if (element.children) {
    for (const child of element.children) {
      parseElement(child, domElement);
    }
  }
  parentNode.appendChild(domElement);
};


for (const element of data) {
  parseElement(element);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body></body>

</html>
```

---

If for some reason you cannot change the structure, this can still be done. However, the current structure is quite poor and does not allow to have, for instance, the same element twice (e.g. one div with two p).

```js
var data = {
  "htmlcontent": {
    "div": {
      "p": "hello world",
      "div": {
        "p": "next content"
      }
    }
  }
};


/**
 * Parses an element from JSON.
 * @param {!Object} element Element from JSON to parse.
 * @param {!DOMElement} parentNode Element to which append this one.
 */
const parseElement = (element, parentNode = document.body) => {
  for (const [tagName, contents] of Object.entries(element)) {
    const domElement = document.createElement(tagName);
    if (typeof contents === 'string') {
      domElement.innerText = contents;
    } else if (typeof contents === 'object') {
      parseElement(contents, domElement);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unknow contents.');
    }
    parentNode.appendChild(domElement);
  }
};

const htmlElements = data.htmlcontent;
parseElement(htmlElements);
```

Comment: with the above suggested structure i'm fine, but i'm a never programmer , so can you help me with the existing structure

Comment: Added solution without modifying input data.

Answer (score 1):

Given your object structure, this is what I would do:

```js
var data = {
  "htmlContent": {
    "div": {
      "p": "hello world",
      "div": {
        "p": "next content"
      }
    }
  }
}

function createElementsFromObject(parent, obj) {
  for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    let el;
    switch (typeof obj[key]) {
      case "string":
        el = document.createElement(key);
        el.textContent = obj[key];
        break;
      case "object":
        el = document.createElement(key);
        createElementsFromObject(el, obj[key]);
        break;
    }
    parent.appendChild(el);
  }
}

createElementsFromObject(app, data.htmlContent);
console.log(app.innerHTML);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
}

div > div {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

div > div > div {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

p {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Problem with your structure is, that it won't allow for an element to have both `textContent` and `children`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best way to use a javascript template system, storing html like you're doing will get you to a bottleneck, just imagine if you have to store a navbar with multiple `ul` and `li` for menus and submenus.

You should consider using a template system like [mustash](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) (here is a [quick introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljiXrvRsQiw) to the subject)

If you want to get more advance use a javascript framework like [vue](https://vuejs.org/), [angular](https://angularjs.org/), or [react](https://reactjs.org/), it will greatly help you and guide you to get rapidly a fully working web app (if you're a beginner I highly recommend you to use vuejs)